# Delete rest string after a specific word in python

Tags: python

I want to delete  words in the string if `\x` comes in that word. I am trying this

```
text = "Joe is \xd8\xae\xd8\xa7\ a boy."
sep = "\x"
rest = text.split(sep, 1)[0]
print(rest)
```

But it gives;

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \xXX escape

Comment: the \x things are unicode escapes not literal \x's in your string. \x followed by nothing is an invalid escape so python complains.

Comment: `\x` is not really in your string... XY problem? do you want to filter out "bizarre" chars from your output?

Comment: one workaround is to use raw strings... `text = r"Joe is \xd8\xae\xd8\xa7\ a boy."` and `sep = r"\x"` see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings for a table on escape sequences...

Comment: Please update your question for what you really want/mean. Your comments about expected output of `Joe is a boy` do not match your question. Also, do you want the `.` at the end of the sentence? and how about the extra backslash all by itself before " a boy."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: You clarified that you're really trying to remove non-printable characters from a string.

```
import re

text = "Joe is \xd8\xae\xd8\xa7\ a boy."
#                              ^
#            stray backslash --|
sep = r'[^\x20-\x7e]' # Any non-printable character
rest = re.sub(sep, '', text)
# rest = 'Joe is \\ a boy.'
print(rest)
# Joe is \ a boy.
```

The backslash is there because it's in your input.

---

Python is trying to interpret the `\x` in the string below as a command to insert a character using a hexadecimal value.

```
    sep = "\x"
         ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \xXX escape
```

To fix it, either escape the backslash like this:

```
sep = "\\x"
```

Or better, use a raw string like this:

```
sep = r"\x"
```

which tells Python not to expand the `\x` inside the string.

---

If you're trying to split on non-printable characters...

```
import re

text = "Joe is \xd8\xae\xd8\xa7\ a boy."
# Not(^) a printable ascii character (0x20 - 0x7e)
sep = r'[^\x20-\x7e]'
first_part, rest = re.split(sep, text, maxsplit=1)
print(first_part)
```

---

If you're really looking for a literal `'\x'`...

```
# Raw (r'') strings will not evaluate your backslash in this
# string.
sep = r'\x'
first_part, rest = text.split(sep, maxsplit=1)
print(first_part)
```

Answer (score 1):

**IF YOU WANT TO PRINT ONLY VALID ASCII CHARACTERS**

```
text = "Joe is \xd8\xae\xd8\xa7\ a boy."
filtered = ''

for x in text:
    try:
        x.encode('ascii')
        filtered += x
    except:
        continue
print(filtered)
```

output

> Joe is \ a boy.

If you want to filter only valid alphabetic characters you can use .isalpha(). If you want to allow numeric characters too, you can use .isalnum() instead of .isalpha(). *\x* is an escape character so you method will not work.

```
text = "Joe is \xd8\xae\xd8\xa7\ a boy."
filtered = ''

for x in text:
    if x.isalpha() or x.isspace():
        filtered += x
print(filtered)
```

output

> Joe is  a boy

**Update**

> Edit
>   **If the above two method does not work for you individually and if you only want *Joe is a boy* as output**

```
text = "Joe is \xd8\xae\xd8\xa7\ a boy."
filtered = ''

for x in text:
    try:
        x.encode('ascii')
        filtered += x
    except:
        continue
print(filtered)
new_filtered = ''

for x in filtered:
    if x.isalpha() or x.isspace():
        new_filtered += x
print(new_filtered)
```

Output

> Joe is a boy

you can also use regular expression

Comment: the output is wrong. On my IDE it is printing as `Joe is ØØ a boy` but i need `Joe is a boy`

Comment: use the updated program i gave, where checking for ascii char is done

Comment: which one of the above two methods you tried? first one or second one?

Comment: First program is printing `Joe is \ a boy.` and second program `Joe is ØØ a boy`.

Comment: run both the methods simultaneously. One after one. Just change *text = filtered*  before second method. Let me know if using both first and second method simultaneously worked or not.

Comment: Your code doesn't work for python3 since `\xd8`: `Ø` character is consider as alphanumeric. http://www.charbase.com/00d8-unicode-latin-capital-letter-o-with-stroke

Comment: Ya that's why I am saying. Filter only ASCII characters using the first program. You will get *Joe is \ a boy.* Then pass this string to second program. You will only get *Joe is a boy*

Answer (score 1):

"\x" is not consider as charater you should make a raw string of your test string to make "\x" consider as character :

```
text = r"Joe is \xd8\xae\xd8\xa7\ a boy."
sep = r"\x"
rest = text.split(sep, 1)[0]
print(rest)
```

**EDIT**

to have `Joe is a boy` :

```
text = r"Joe is \xd8\xae\xd8\xa7\ a boy."
sep = r"\x"
text=text.split(" ")
rest=[i for i in text if sep not in i]
output=" ".join(rest)
print(output)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `r` with the string to treat it as a raw string. So the escape codes will be ignored.

```
text = r"Joe is \xd8\xae\xd8\xa7\ a boy."
sep = r"\x"
list=text.split(" ")
t=" "
for i in list:
        temp=i.split(sep)
        if len(temp) < 2:
                t+=' '+i
print t
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Joe is a boy.
```

Comment: @waqas try this now